# CSS positioning not working on custom component

Tags: css, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/71j1omvz66

I am trying to move this chat component over, but cannot get it to move at all...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's set explicitly in the package itself.

try this to override the style:

```
.sc-launcher {
  right: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that moves the launcher itself it looks like I will just need to override all the other ones too. Thank you